# Не могу добавить данные сессии в базу данных

Tags: php, codeigniter, сессия

Как работать с session class и как записать данные сессии в таблицу?

1. Создал базу данных как написано в документации, имя не менял,
   user_agent стоит 120 символов.
2. В config файле добавил/установил следующие поля:

   ```
   $autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');
   $autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'form');

   $config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
   $config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
   $config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
   $config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
   $config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
   $config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
   $config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
   $config['sess_use_database'] = true;
   $config['sess_table_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
   ```
3. Установил ключ шифрования
4. Настроил свойства базы данных, ввел корректно данные

Затем идет следующая структура:

```
class Main extends CI_Controller {
  public function index() 
    if ($this->session->userdata('is_logged')) {
      $this->load->view('pages/blocks_view');
    } else {
      $this->load->view('pages/authorization_view');
    }
  }


  public function login() {
    if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
      if($_POST['password'] == 'root' && $_POST['login'] == 'admin') {
        $session_data = array('is_logged' => true);
        $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
        redirect('');
      }
    }
  }


  public function logout() {
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    redirect('');
  }
}
```

После всех этих действий, таблица ci_sessions пустая, без изменений, даже не знаю, в каком направлении копать

**Обновление**

Позвольте уточнить, `codeigniter` ведь сам заполняет таблицу `ci_sessions`? Или заполнение этой таблицы следует производить самостоятельно? Если самостоятельно, то тогда у меня еще больший конфуз, но в документации написано "Он также сохраняет данные сессий в таблице базы данных, для большей безопасности, что позволяет ассоциировать идентификатор сессии и куку пользователя. По умолчанию сохраняется только кука. Если вы выберете использование базы данных, вы должны создать таблицу для сессий..."

**Обновление 2**

Получилось что-то сдвинуть, теперь начал выдавать ошибки базы данных

> Unknown column 'data' in 'field list'
>   Filename: libraries/Session/drivers/Session_database_driver.php

Похоже придется что то править в исходниках? Каждый раз при обновлении страницы генерятся данные, но так как верхняя проблема, то никак работать не получается.

Comment: а вы попробуйте написать для этого всего тесты. ну то есть заменив все вводы в бд функциями вроде `echo`. Так сказать подебажте

Comment: нет, я думаю все правильно, это я без знания предметной области решил дать вам глупый совет и ввел вас в заблуждение, простите за халатность. Но тем не менее, попробуйте произвести какие-то тесты, действительно ли сессия существует, isset проверьте на переменных

Comment: Ваша догадка верна, данные, которые нужно записывать в таблицу вовсе не генерятся (userdata имеет только элемент __ci_last_regenerate), но как это вылечить

Comment: Ну тут я вам уже даже при всем желании не помогу, область не моя

Comment: Поправьте `$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';`

Comment: @DotProx По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Шаблонный SQL-запрос из документации создает поля с названиями, которые не соответствуют тем, к которым стучится фреймворк в файле session_database_driver. Для того, чтобы записывались данные, я поправил названия полей, но ip, user_agent, user_data записываются некорректно, полагаю, что решение кроется в тех же местах, но так как мои знания php не очень большого уровня, глубже копаться в исходниках фреймворка не решаюсь

Исправленная таблица, которая хотя бы заводит генерацию как-то данных, но корректную запись клиента сессии я так и добился

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ci_sessions` (
  id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
  ip_address varchar(16) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
  user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  timestamp int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
  data text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY `last_activity_idx` (`timestamp `) );
```